# Picture are getting lost on the first run of a slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

So I built a slideshow that changes picture and text by pressing button and by timer.For some reason the pictures are not showing on the first loop of the slideshow but only from the second one not by the button and not by the timer.
The website is music theme and for school project.

PS. I dont know why the JS / Jquery doesn't read the id from the html file dont know if I need to add anything but if you know it will be helpful but not super important

EDIT:

Not sure why but when I used the code on [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uk8q2fp9/) the only problem I had was the jumpy text when changing pictures which I have also on the file. If I'm using different text language which is rtl type can it destroy it?

HTML

```js
        $('#SlideShow img').css({
            width: screen.width * .4,
            left: screen.width * .1

        });
        $('#NextButton img').css({
            width: screen.width * 0.04,
            left: screen.width * .1
        });
        $('#NextButton').css({
            left: screen.width * .5,
            top:screen.height * .2
        });
        $('#BackButton').css({
            left: screen.width * .06,
            top: screen.height * .2
        });
        $("#BackButton img").css({
            width: screen.width * 0.04,
            right: screen.width * .1
        });
        $("#ShortText").css({
            width: screen.width * .45
        })
        //Picture change code Auto+Buttons
        setInterval("Change()", 40000)
        function Change() {
            $('#SlideShow img:first').fadeOut(1000).next().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('#SlideShow');
            $('#ShortText div:first').fadeOut(1000).next().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('#ShortText');

        }

        $(function() {
            $('#SlideShow img:gt(0)').hide();//Hides all the pictures accpet the first one (img:gt refers to all the img inside the id and the aplly it to all the next index item after the number in the ())
            $('#ShortText div:gt(0)').hide();
    
        
            $('#BackButton').click(function () {
                $('#SlideShow img:first').fadeOut(1000);//Hide the first inexed img
                $('#SlideShow img:last').fadeIn(1000).prependTo('#SlideShow');//Show the last indexed img .prependTo insert the first element to the last one
                $("#ShortText div:first").fadeOut(1000);
                $("#ShortText div:last").fadeIn(1000).prependTo("#ShortText");
           
            });

            $('#NextButton').click(function () {
                $('#SlideShow img:first').fadeOut(1000).next().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('#SlideShow');//.appendTo= insert the object as the last element .next=Aplly to the next elemnt .end= Stop all the code until now in the chain.
                $('#ShortText div:first').fadeOut(1000).next().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('#ShortText');
               
            });
        });
```

```css
#SlideShow img {
    position:absolute;
    }
    #NextButton{
    position:absolute;
    }
    #BackButton{
    position:absolute;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="SlideShow">
        <img src="Pics/Classic%20Music.jpg" />
        <a href="Rock.aspx"><img src="Pics/RockNRoll.jpg" /></a>
        <img src="Pics/Metal.jpg" />
      
    </div>
      <div id="ShortText">
            <div><h1>First header</h1>
             <p>First text</p>
            </div>
          <div>
              <a href="Rock.aspx"><h1>Second Header</h1></a>
              <p>Second Text</p>
          </div>
          <div>
              <h1>Third header</h1>
              <p>Third text</p>
          </div>
      </div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uk8q2fp9/)

Comment: your code is note working add working code, or create a fiddle

Comment: Added [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uk8q2fp9/) but also added an edit to the post

Comment: the problem is you put one image in a tag, check this updated fiddle i think this is what you need: https://jsfiddle.net/uk8q2fp9/1/

Comment: Wait I can't use it with the 'a' tag? Or I just need to add the tag to all the other images?(that what I have in mind)

Comment: you coded jquery targeting img tag only so there is no code for a tag which is sibling of img tags in your code.if you want to take img in a tag so others as well. did my fiddle worked for you?